# jquery hiding things in form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a search form where i have text boxes and drop downs and some of it is not working. It works when i click on an option and then hides it. if i pick another option it shows back up.

here is example.

i have a text box which i hide another one if you pick certain options then it shows or hides. if i choose something and then go to my nav menu and then come back to form the one box that should be hidden shows. Here is the code i am using to hide things. I am not sure why it is not setting back to default and hiding them on page load. This is on a razor view page.

```
 @*hidefields - Spec Guide*@


//condition fields for the end user request form make sure you change the field ID to yours. 
$(document).ready(function () {
    //check to see if you are on the end users request page
    if (location.pathname === '/Reporting/Summary') {
        //if (document.location.href='/Tickets/New'){
        //toggle the field ,description and title invisible
        $('label for="CustomFieldValue@field.FieldID":contains(* On what page of the Spec Guide:)').toggle();
        $('input#CustomFieldValue3').parent().toggle();

        //monitor the dropdown field
        $('select#CustomFieldValue2').change(function(endUserselect) {
            //grab the value of the dropdown
            var userSelection = $('select#CustomFieldValue2 option:selected').text();

            //do the compare and toggle the field ,description and title visible 
            if (userSelection === 'Spec Guide') {
                $('label for="CustomFieldValue@field.FieldID":contains(* On what page of the Spec Guide:)').toggle();
                $('input#CustomFieldValue3').parent().toggle();
            }
            //hide them again if the user changes his mind
            else {
                $('label for="CustomFieldValue@field.FieldID":contains(* On what page of the Spec Guide:)').hide();
                $('input#CustomFieldValue3').parent().hide();
            }

        });

    }
});
@*hidefields - Spec Guide*@
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a cache problem.

Sometimes when you navigate to another page and click the back button, the javascript is not executed again. Instead you are shown the last version of the form.

I think an alternative to this (if you want it to always work) could be the unload event to reset the page.

The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event. Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even a page reload will first create an unload event.

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    // Here set the default options/hide/show dom elements for your form
});
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I think you are right but i not sure how to just hide it on load. I made a function to hide the above and still does it. I think i am writing the code wrong.

Comment: i tried your code and this    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){{
    $('label for="CustomFieldValue@field.FieldID":contains(* On what page of the Spec Guide:)').hide();
                $('input#CustomFieldValue3').parent().hide();
    
});

</script>

Comment: Add the html and css of that form and I'll see if I can help you with the reset method.